# Enzyme shallow rendering for Angular2?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, enzyme

Trying to test my UI components without rendering the whole child component tree inside, it was super easy to do in react/enzyme - is there anything similar in Angular2 world?

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render
https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-render

I am the developer for [`shallow-render`](https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render). I was a big fan of the enzyme model and you'll see a lot of similarities.

The goals I set out to solve were:
* Automatically follow the dependency tree by following the Angular module tree.
* Render ONLY the component in-test (everything else is a mock that shallow-renders).

It currently supports Angular 5x and will follow future Angular releases as they come out.